# Map Routes for Pagination in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagination

I am using a Pagination class very similar to the one used in the NerdDinner example.  The pagination aspect works fine but I am struggling with getting all the routes to work properly.

Currently we have one `MapRoute` set:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{page}", // URL with parameters
            new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                page = UrlParameter.Optional
            } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

We want the URL to be, instead of `/mycontroller/myaction/1/5`, to be `/mycontroller/myaction/1/page5` so it makes more sense to the user. I cannot find a way to do this at the moment.

Secondly how do we set up the routes so that actions can used with pagination too.  I.e. `/controller/page1` instead of `/controller/index/page1`

Comment: Using `"{controller}/{action}/{id}/page{page}"` will make your URL look like `/mycontroller/myaction/1/page5`. Regarding your second question, could you elaborate on what you mean by `how do we set up the routes so that actions can used with pagination too`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have two routes:

First for pagination(default controller and action will be used):

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "home/{id}/{page}", // URL with parameters
        new
        {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional,
            page = UrlParameter.Optional
        } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

Last route for all controllers:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{page}", // URL with parameters
        new
        {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional,
            page = UrlParameter.Optional
        } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

So with above routes /home/1/page5 will be handled by home controller index action,
but someController/someAction/1/page5 by second route.

*You should know that first you need place routes that handle less urls and than - common routes, like second route above for all controllers.*

Also inside of controller action you can retreview route parameter like this:

```
string page = RouteData.Values["page"];
```

so for url home/1/page5 in above example page will be equal 'page5', than you can parse this string in order to get page number.

As for me i use following method to get parameters from route data, post body, query string:

```
 protected T GetQueryParam<T>(String name, T defValue = default(T))
        {
            String param = HttpContext.Request.QueryString.Get(name);
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(param))
                param = HttpContext.Request.Params[name];
            if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty(param))
                param = (String) RouteData.Values[name] ?? String.Empty;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(param) )
                return defValue;

            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(param, typeof(T));
        }
```

So, if you need get page using above method you just need do following:

```
var page = GetQueryParam<string>("page");// in case if page parameter not exists default value for type will be returned
```